# excel programatically merge all rows with equal values in column z

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a dataimport macro, and I want to merge all rows in a dataset that have equal values in column x, and then I want to get a row that represents the average of group x[y] x being the column, and y being the value of the column x for that particular grouping.

Is there a simple function to do this, or must I create an extensive loop with a lot of spare cycles?

**Explicitation:**
So my dataset looks like

```
 A    |    B     |    C
 1         2          4
 1         2          5
 2         7          3
 2         5          1
 3         2          1
 1         5          6
```

Now I want to merge rows by column A value, so all A's with equal value get the rest of their rows averaged so I would get somethin that looked like:

```
 A    |    B     |    C
 1         3          5
 2         6          2
 3         2          1
```

So far I've been trying to loop over the possible values of column A (1 to 10) manually by this function, but it keeps crashing excel, and I can't figure out why, I must have an endless loop somewhere in this function:

```
Function MergeRows(sheet, column, value)
Dim LastRow
Dim LastCol
Dim numRowsMerged
Dim totalValue

numRowsMerged = 1
LastRow = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastCol = sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For iRow = LastRow - 1 To 1 Step -1
        'enter loop if the cell value matches what we're trying to merge
        Do While Cells(iRow, column) = value
               For iCol = 1 To LastCol
                'skip the column that we're going to use as merging value, and skip the column if it contains 3 (ikke relevant)
                If Not (iCol = column) And Not (Cells(iRow, iCol) = 3) Then
                    Cells(iRow, iCol) = (Cells(iRow, iCol) * numRowsMerged + Cells(iRow + 1, iCol)) / (numRowsMerged + 1)
                End If
               Next iCol
            'delete the row merged
            Rows(iRow + 1).Delete
        Loop

        'add one to the total number of rows merged
        numRowsMerged = numRowsMerged + 1
    Next iRow
End With

End Function
```

**solution**
I ended up creating a range that I would gradually extend using Union, like this:

```
  Function GetRowRange(sheet, column, value) As range
Dim LastRow
Dim LastCol
Dim numRowsMerged
Dim totalValue
Dim rowRng As range
Dim tempRng As range
Dim sheetRange As range

numRowsMerged = 1
Set sheetRange = sheet.UsedRange
LastRow = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastCol = sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow Step 1
        'enter loop if the cell value matches what we're trying to merge
        If (sheetRange.Cells(iRow, column) = value) Then
            Set tempRng = range(sheetRange.Cells(iRow, 1), sheetRange.Cells(iRow, LastCol))
            If (rowRng Is Nothing) Then
                Set rowRng = tempRng
            Else
                Set rowRng = Union(rowRng, tempRng)
            End If
        End If

        'add one to the total number of rows merged
        numRowsMerged = numRowsMerged + 1
    Next iRow
End With
Set GetRowRange = rowRng
End Function
```

Comment: are you looking for ultimately -> `Group1 | Avg of Group1, Group2 | Avg of Group2, Group3 | Avg of Group3`?

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail?? Not sure I understand what it is you're looking to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? Since you wanted VBA code, I have not used Pivots but used a simpler option; `formulas` to calculate your average.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim wsIlRow As Long, wsOlRow As Long, r As Long, i As Long
    Dim itm

    '~~> Chnage this to the relevant sheets
    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    '~~> Work with the input sheet
    With wsI
        wsIlRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '~~> get unique values from Col A
        For i = 1 To wsIlRow
            On Error Resume Next
            col.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, """" & .Range("A" & i).Value & """"
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End With

    r = 1

    '~~> Write unique values to Col A
    With wsO
        For Each itm In col
            .Cells(r, 1).Value = itm
            r = r + 1
        Next

        wsOlRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Use a simple formula to find the average
        For i = 1 To wsOlRow
            .Range("B" & i).Value = Application.Evaluate("=AVERAGE(IF(" & wsI.Name & _
                                    "!A1:A" & wsIlRow & "=" & .Range("A" & i).Value & _
                                    "," & wsI.Name & "!B1:B" & wsIlRow & "))")

            .Range("C" & i).Value = Application.Evaluate("=AVERAGE(IF(" & wsI.Name & _
                                    "!A1:A" & wsIlRow & "=" & .Range("A" & i).Value & _
                                    "," & wsI.Name & "!C1:C" & wsIlRow & "))")
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm sure it works. Meanwhile I came up with another solution, but thank you very much, I hope it will be helpful to others with similar problems - can't award bounty yet though

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do with a pivot table.

Here's a picture of the end result.
[image: Excel pivot table]

Comment: You can (and I think *should*) do this without VBA code. Select your table, Insert tab -> PivotTable, and you're off to the races.

Comment: my problem is that I need to do this as part of a routine that saves people from doing many manual transactions (prone to human errors), so I need to do it programatically in my context

Comment: If you were to do this in code, you would give your users an xls file with some VBA and instructions on how to execute the code. Could you give them a file with instructions and a place to import the information? Then they could refresh the table.

Comment: I'm looking to automate this as much as possible, creating new rules that need to be followed to cobnvert this data into something usable would undermine the idea behind creating a macro for importing and converting data effortlessly

Comment: @Jakob. A pivot table is definitely the answer here. Record a macro where you make the pivot table out of your data. Then on each succesive run, have the macro link to the new data source and create the pivot table

Comment: Thank you for offering the bounty, @Jakob. If you were trying to get more attention for your question by offering a bounty, then perhaps you should have waited to accept the answer. Waiting would allow others to produce new answers or vote on the existing ones.